# C1083 Cannot open include file: 'iostream', 'vector' and more

Tags: c++, include

First the story:

I was working on my own project, just messing with C++, renderers and such. I wanted to include Vulkan for future, so I downloaded the SDK from LunarG and CMaked it using Niko Kauppi's YouTube Tutorial.

Now, the problems.

I included the libraries and such, but when I tried building the project (no changes made, except adding the vulkan stuff) it gave me lots C1083 errors, it cannot open include files like 'iostream', 'vector', 'deque', 'cstddef' and 'GL/glu.h'.

I then removed the Vulkan libraries and such, but the problem still persist, I tried rebuilding, comparing properties with a fresh project and installing VS 2015 Community again.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community, latest updates, OS Windows 10 64.

Comment: So reinstalling VS and create a new project did not solve the issue?

Comment: you can bring missing files from another vs 2015 and copy them to  yours.

Comment: Please clarify: A fresh project can build, but once you add in Vulkan the project is forevermore broken?

Comment: And you're sure you created a _C++_ project? You didn't remove predefined include paths when adding those for your third-party libraries?

Comment: @Raindrop7: Such a blunt approach without understanding the root cause is likely to just make things worse.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes that's true. messing with things unconsciously costs dearly.

Comment: Oh great derp.. the 'inherit from parent of project defaults' was ticked off. Probably cause I was in a hurry and wanted to include the dependencies quickly, then clicked it when trying to reach OK button. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'inherit from parent or project defaults' was ticked off in 'Include Directiories'. Derp.